# An error occurred while running subprocess cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

Command failed with exit code 1: F:\ionic\BarcodeScanner\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b F:\ionic\BarcodeScanner\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: what command are you running? can you also run it with --verbose as mentioned?

Comment: What command did you run ? Did you try other commands ?